# Can MS SQL Server 2008/2012 cache SELECT query results

Tags: sql-server-2008, caching

Can MS SQL Server cache select query results just by itself and if so how do I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't cache actual results (like the [MySQL query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html)).

however the data pages that are read during a `SELECT` are first brought into the [buffer cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337525%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Subsequent requests reading the same data can thus be served quicker than the initial request without needing a trip to disc.

Comment: Are there any tools, which would enable caching MS SQL Server selects without knowing anything of the actual selects - CACHE-ANY-SELECT type of thing?

Comment: @user1514042 - There are various third party caching solutions such as mentioned here http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/05/picking-your-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do a way to do this might be to create indexed views

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx